# Athletes under the Olympics flag competing in team sports

Tags: trivia, olympics

The Russian Olympic team has been banned from the 2018 Pyeongchang Winter Olympics due to government supported doping allegations. However, [168 athletes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Athletes_from_Russia_at_the_2018_Winter_Olympics#Competitors) from Russia were permitted to participate in the Olympics headed by the international committee of Olympic Athletes from Russia (OAR) under the Olympic flag.

Similarly, the Russian team was banned from the 2016 Summer Olympics and I asked 
[Athletes who have won Olympic medals under the olympic flag](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/athletes-who-have-won-olympic-medals-under-the-olympic-flag). This question focused on why the athletes who won medals were competing as independent individuals.

The OAR Hockey team has the [best odds](http://www.oddsshark.com/nhl/odds-win-2018-mens-olympic-ice-hockey-tournament) of winning the Hockey gold medal in the 2018 games. Since the answers to the aforementioned question didn't list any medal winners in team sports, I'm wondering how many times, if any, athletes under the Olympic flag competed in team sports? Please list the sport, year, and the results of each team.

Comment: The [Unified Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Team_at_the_Olympics) competed under the Olympic Flag, but for somewhat different reasons. Do you want to include their results? (There's a lot of them as they were just about a full Soviet team).

Comment: wow didn't know about that, it's before I was born. For the Unified Team lets only look at the medal winners

Comment: Refugees were allowed to compete under the Olympic flag in the Rio games.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_Olympians_at_the_Olympic_Games this seems to have quite a lot of information answering all of the questions here.

Answer (score 1):

at both the 1992 winter and summer olympics the countries from the former soviet union competed as the unified team. The unified team competed in the following team sports. 
Ice Hockey (1992 winter olympics)
Basketball (1992 summer olympics) (men's and women's)
Handball (1992 summer olympics) (men's and women's)
Field Hockey (1992 summer olympics) (men's)
Volleyball (1992 summer olympics) (men's and women's)
Water Polo (1992 summer olympics)